# Oracle APEX: How to open different inline dialogs based on link column value

Tags: oracle-apex

I have below report in my page and two static regions as inline dialog.
[image]

First inline dialog static ID: **YesFlag**
Second inline dialog static ID: **NoFlag**

Tried entering below code in link URL

```
javascript:$s('P1_EMPID','#EMPNO#');openModal('YesFlag');
```

The problem here is, if I click "Yes" or "No", its opening only first inline dialog. Unable to figure out how to call inline dialog based on column value. Appreciate if there are any alternate methods to achieve this.

Thanks,
Richa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easiest to add a class to the icon using html expression, like this:

```
<span class="fa fa-badge-check dialog1-js" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Then create a dynamic action on click of jquery selector `.dialog1-js` with action "Open Region" of your region.
I put together an example in your workspace, app 2579, page 2.

If you want, you can also pass row specific data and use that in your dynamic actions. Best place to start is this youtube video from Dan McGhan https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzqFXTnAIr8

Comment: Koen Lostrie you are the best. Thank you again for kind help.

Comment: I have a question. If I want to open two different inline dialogs within same column, then I should use case statement and should pass the html tag with different class right?

Comment: Yes, you could include the class name in your query (suppose it is aliased as "CLASS_NAME") and then reference it in the html expressions as #CLASS_NAME#

Comment: Ok let me try it. Thank you Koen Losrrie